# Load a dynamic shared library into db2 server

Tags: db2

I have a shared library which containts implementation(language C) of some utility db2 procedures and functions. Now i want to call these utility functions from db2cmd as,

`select epiProcLibVer() from sysibm.sysdummy1`

To make this these utiliy functions installed into DB2 db server, i have placed this shared library (`libDB2CLIWrapper.so`) into `<DB2InstallFolder>/sqllib/function`

I have restarted the db2 instace to pick and load this library into shared memory of the db server.

Still i am getting the below error @ db2 cmd as below:

`db2 => select epiproclibver() from sysibm.sysdummy1
SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "EPIPROCLIBVER" of type "FUNCTION" 
having compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884`

Now i would like to know whether is it the correct procedure to make a shared library load into db2 db server? how to access the functions in this shared library from sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be a starting point?

```
CREATE FUNCTION epiproclibver () RETURNS INT
  EXTERNAL NAME 'libDB2CLIWrapper!epiProcLibVer'
  NOT FENCED 
  SCRATCHPAD
  VARIANT
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION
  LANGUAGE C PARAMETER STYLE DB2SQL NO SQL:
```